# Validate a header parameter with Joi, nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I want to check one parameter (docsLimit in this case) of a header of a HTTP request. So i did this:

```
const {
  celebrate,
  Joi,
} = require('celebrate');
const joiObjectId = require('joi-objectid');

Joi.objectId = joiObjectId(Joi);

const limit = celebrate({
  headers: Joi.object().keys({
    docsLimit: Joi.number()
      .required()
      .default(10),
  }).options({ allowUnknown: true })
});

module.exports = limit;
```

in app.js:

```
app.get(path, limit, getDocuments);
```

I have to say that I am new to nodejs and especially Joi but that seems to have sense to me. That is wrong instead, because if I send a string in the headers it accepts it anyway, even if I precised it to be a number. If I remove the *.options({ allowUnknown: true })* then it never passes, even there's a number. It says "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" and returns a json saying that "limit is not allowd". Which is the way to check a parameter in headers with Joi?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Headers are always strings? Can you show us what exactly you are sending?

Comment: @Bergi thank you! The problem was that the header is always a string so I shouldn't do Joi.number(). I use Joi.string() and I check with a regex in order to be a number. After that i convert it into a number before I use it! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the header is always a string so I shouldn't do Joi.number(). I should use Joi.string() and after that, I check with a regex in order to be a number. Finally I convert it into a number before using it!